# Complex Form of the Fourier transform

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Hello i am having trouble understanding where to start when calculating the fourier series here because I am confused on the question itself, I thought the equation was already in complex form.... does it mean to reduce?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoyAe.png)

and why is this equation including i^{ik_j x} are there any sources I can read about this derivation? Why / what is this formula representing

Comment: You better type the question itself on your post. As you can see, the definition of $f$ in the link you provide is messed up. You can aslo google "Complex Fourier Series". There's a lot ot stuff about it in the web.

Comment: See [Exponential form coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Exponential_form_coefficients). Perhaps they want you to calculate the specific complex Fourier series for the defined function versus the general formula which was provided. Perhaps they also want you to reduce the specific complex Fourier series for the defined function into sums over real $\sin$ and $\cos$ terms.

Comment: I believe the function of interest is actually defined as $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & -\pi <x<-1 \\
 1 & -1<x<1 \\
 0 & 1<x<\pi  \\
\end{array}\right.$$ which is an even function of $x$ and hence the complex exponential Fourier series will simplify to real $cos$ terms.